# How to write unit test for a create method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'd like to write unit test for my add method in C#. My method got a dog entity and the type as parameters. And this method add it to the db via my service.

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Dog dog, string type)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var d = new Dog();

            d.Name = dog.Name;
            d.NumOfLegs = dog.NumOfLegs;
            d.BirthdayDate = dog.BirthdayDate;

            if(type == "mom"){
              //when the dog is a mom, dog.Childrens got default puppies
              InitChildrenOfMomDog(dog);
            }

            dogService.Insert(dog);

            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }

        return View(dog);
    }
```

I'd like to check in unit tests, my method works correctly and default puppies added ok to the dog, or if the user added valid (or not) properties... I'm a little confused at this point.

Comment: Technically a pure "unit" test most likely wouldn't test a function like this that relies on the Mvc framework - you probably want to look at extracting the code between `IsValid` and `return` (and knowing how to mock `dogService`). Or do you want an integration test that simulates what happens when this API is called by a web client?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to understand mocking, I read about it, it'd be great in this case, but I'm confused, how should I do it.

Comment: Really depends what platform you're using. But as long as `dogService` is declared as some sort of interface that can be replaced with a mocked type that exposes the same functions, it shouldn't be hard. Btw have you actually tested this from a web client and confirmed it's storing new Dogs in the database?  Just that normally I'd expect to see a `SaveChanges()` call somewhere (but maybe it's inside your 'Insert' function).

Comment: I checked it, and dogs saved to the db correctly. As you said, the service is an interface in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refactor your Controller's code into a separate view-model class. This allows the view-model to be directly tested without interacting with the MVC framework. See the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) pattern.

**Controller**
Creates, builds, and returns a view-model class. Only logic limited specifically to the view should be here, if any, as it will not be directly testable.

**ViewModel**
Performs all of the logical operations for the view, such as database querying. Can be tested directly tested.

---

#### Code Example

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Dog dog, string type)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(dog);

    var vm = new AddDogVM(dogService);
    vm.Add(dog, type);

    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

**View Model Class**

```
public class AddDogVM
{
    private IDogService _dogService

    public AddDogVM(IDogService dogService)
    {
        _dogService = dogService;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Dog dog, string type)
    {
        var d = new Dog();

        d.Name = dog.Name;
        d.NumOfLegs = dog.NumOfLegs;
        d.BirthdayDate = dog.BirthdayDate;

        if (type == "mom") {
            InitChildrenOfMomDog(dog);
        }

        _dogService.Insert(dog);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public void Test()
{
    var dogService = SomeMockingFramework.CreateSubstituteFor<IDogService>();
    var vm = new AddDogVM(dogService);
    vm.Add(...);

    // Assertions
}
```

Comment: `dogService` is not declared in the VM. It should be injected.

Comment: It's so much clearer and more understandable! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I completely overlooked the service.